PromQL to measure total runtime of GKE workload within current month
I have been trying to set up an alert in Google Monitoring whenever a gke workload is running for too long in the current month.
However because there is a limitation of 24h (actually 23h30 minutes) GCP can look back, this is not possible directly.
I have tried some queries in MQL but always blocked at the look back period.
Now I am exploring with PromQL, below is how far I went .
Checking whether an instance is present in an instance group:
avg(avg_over_time(compute_googleapis_com:instance_group_size{instance_group_name=~'.*pool-test.*'}[30d:1d] ))

Or also different approach , looking for how long containers s been running :
avg(kubernetes_io:container_uptime{monitored_resource="k8s_container",cluster_name="test-gke",namespace_name="app",container_name='nginx-1'} /3600 )
by (pod_name)

But this one does not let me use [30d:1h]
Those are not perfect probably to measure uptime (how long a workload s been running) but that s all I could find . Not sure if there are better ways .
Now, I need to measure from 1st day of the month until now , and ideally get the data once a day.
I tried to play with time() or timestamp() but I dont understand the syntax and how to calculate : ' 1st day of the month - now '
If anyone knows how to do that in PromQL or advice , that'd be helpful.

In MQL , can specify start time and end time in query itself by using within operator. As per google docs for MQL queries:

within - Specifies the time range of the query output.


| fetch <some metric> 

--- rest of query --- 
within 'd <first day of the month> '    (# omitting second arg means end=now )
But again, I do not know how to specify  whether in MQL or PromQL .
